# While converting doc to html graphics or shapes are not converting into html format

Tags: html, apache-poi, doc

We want to display doc file into dialog box on browser. That is why I convert it into html file. So doc file converted into html successfully but if doc file has graphics or any shapes then it converts into html file. But graphics ware not converting into any html tags like img or etc and not shown in file displayed on UI,

So how we convert doc file which has graphics or shape into html.

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream (baseDir + fileName);
HWPFDocument wordDocument = new HWPFDocument (input);
wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument (wordDocument);
wordToHtmlConverter.setPicturesManager (picmang=new PicturesManager() {
        public String savePicture (byte[] content, PictureType pictureType, String suggestedName, float widthInches, float heightInches) {
            return suggestedName;
        }

    });
org.w3c.dom.Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource (htmlDocument);
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult (outStream);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
    serializer.setOutputProperty (OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    serializer.setOutputProperty (OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    serializer.setOutputProperty (OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
    serializer.transform (domSource, streamResult);
    outStream.close();

    String content = new String (outStream.toByteArray() );
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    String destinationHTMLFile = baseDir + fileName.replace(".docx", "").replace(".doc", "")+".html";
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    File file = new File(destinationHTMLFile);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8"));
    bw.write(content);
```

So please help me out to display doc file in browser.

Answer (score 0):

The [AbstractWordConverter.setPicturesManager](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/converter/AbstractWordConverter.html#setPicturesManager-org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.PicturesManager-) must be done before [AbstractWordConverter.processDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/converter/AbstractWordConverter.html#processDocument-org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore-). And of course the method [PicturesManager.savePicture](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/converter/PicturesManager.html#savePicture-byte:A-org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.PictureType-java.lang.String-float-float-) in `Interface PicturesManager` needs to be filled with functionality for saving the pictures in the class which implements this interface.

Following example takes a `WordDocument.doc` from my home directory and transforms this to HTML including pictures and puts the resulting files (HTML file and image files) in a new created directory `html`. Note, the pictures included in the `WordDocument.doc` must be either `*.gif` or `*.png` or `*.jpg` since the used approach for  [Writing/Saving an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) only supports those types.

```
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.WordToHtmlConverter;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.PicturesManager;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.PictureType;
import org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TestWordToHtmlConverter {

 private static void convertDocToHTML(String docFilePathAndName, String htmlPath, String htmlFileName) throws Exception {

  new File(htmlPath).mkdir();

  HWPFDocument hwpfDocument = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(docFilePathAndName));

  Document newDocument = XMLHelper.getDocumentBuilderFactory().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
  WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(newDocument);

  wordToHtmlConverter.setPicturesManager(
   new PicturesManager() {
    public String savePicture(byte[] content, PictureType pictureType, String suggestedName, float widthInches, float heightInches) {
     /*
     System.out.println(content);
     System.out.println(pictureType);
     System.out.println(suggestedName);
     System.out.println(widthInches);
     System.out.println(heightInches);
     */
     try {
      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
      ImageIO.write(image, pictureType.getExtension(), new File(htmlPath, suggestedName));
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return suggestedName;
    }
   }
  );

  wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(hwpfDocument);

  Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
  transformer.transform(new DOMSource(wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument()),
                        new StreamResult(new File(htmlPath, htmlFileName)));

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  convertDocToHTML("/home/axel/Dokumente/WordDocument.doc", "/home/axel/Dokumente/html", "WordDocument.html");

 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but its not working the html file generated from doc file is not in proper format some content is messing . i want the output as same as doc file.all content in doc and format should be same.

Comment: @shriyash Lakhe: For me it works. I've tested using different `*.doc` files. Can you please provide a sample `*.doc` file where it not works?